# MoSKito monitor: how to collect response status codes?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, monitoring, http-status-codes

I have anotheria/moskito already integrated into the project. It collects and plots the quantity of requests to some REST API endpoints.

Anybody knows how should I tune/adjust it to collect response status codes from the same endpoints on received requests?

upd:I have some endpoint annotated with @Monitor, and I see them as producers on MoSKito-Inspect page, it's already collecting how much each endpoint requested but I need also to monitor:

1. exceptions generated by endpoints
2. status codes if it wasn't 200 (e.g. 500 or 501) for each response for exact API endpoint

Comment: Please add more details for your question.

Comment: Recently updated, could You look if something more should be clarified. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As for the second part of your question, how do you know what status code was returned? If the status code is the return value of your endpoints method, you can annotate this method by

```
CountByReturnValue
```

and if will create a statistic for different return values. If it is something which is part of the return object you will probably do it yourself by creating custom counter, i.e.

```
@Counter
class ReturnCodeCounter(){
    public void status200(){}
    public void status500(){}
    public void status501(){}
}
```

and then whereever you know the return value:

```
ReturnCodeCounter rcc = new RecordCodeCounter(); //this should be classwise variable
...
public void someMethod(){
   ... rcc.status200();
}
```

OR you can create a dynamic counter:

```
class ReturnCodeCounter(){
    @CountByParameter
    public void status(int code){
    }
}
```

and then

```
rcc.status(myStatus);
```

As for the first part of your question, if exception is thrown by an annotated class (your resource i.e.) it will automatically be shown as errors in the producer view (same place where you see requests, time spent etc).

Hope to help, feel free to ask if something is unclear.